# Service Worker instance "id" not surfaced in any interface

Tags: javascript, web-applications, geolocation, service-worker

According to the [spec](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#dfn-service-worker) *A service worker has an associated id (an opaque string), which uniquely identifies itself during the lifetime of its containing service worker registration.*

Sounds good but I see no way in the spec (and certainly not in Chrome of Firefox implementations) of obtaining that id. The client.id on the other hand is equally-spec'd ***and*** fully obtainable. Is there a reason for the inconsistency? An oversight?

Use case: - I the client needs to know when there is a new instance (as opposed to a new version) of a ServiceWorker. That is, no SW update took place, registration is still peachy, but the UA stopped the SW Instance Opaque_id_x earlier in the day and the new one is uniquely identified for this particular registration as Opaque_id_y.

No biggy as I'm relying on the transitory nature of SW Global Scope and will implement: -

```
var doryRegister = [];

. . .

if (!doryRegister[event.source.id]){
     doryRegister[event.source.id] = true;
    event.source.postMessage("Piacere");
}
```

But shouldn't a SW instance have a per-registration-unique id I can get at?

Comment: See https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1076 and https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1077

Comment: Thanks. Good to know that it's not there deliberately :-( self.id for SW and ServiceWorkerRegistration.active.id would be nice!